# Multiple window not working in android webview

Tags: webview, android-webview, razorpay

I have used https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView for my webview app. It is working fine till I use third party payment gateway. I am using razorpay.com for my payment gateway. It is working fine in my website, but didn't work when I call it inside this webview code.

Also, when I click on pay button in webview. It call the javascript of payment gateway, but it get hang as new window not opening.

Please someone help me, what I need to fix here.

Comment: solutions u got  ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?